# Using Gatling for functional testing

Tags: selenium, testing, gatling

I want to get into test automation, and I have already seen selenium that allows to do the functional test. I also saw gatling for performance testing and load/stress tests. I want to know if it is possible to do the functional tests with gatling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example for a functional spec from their documentation:

```
class GatlingFunSpecExample extends GatlingHttpFunSpec { 

  val baseURL = "http://example.com"
  override def httpConf = super.httpConf.header("MyHeader", "MyValue")

  spec {
    http("Example index.html test")
      .get("/index.html")
      .check(pageHeader.exists)
  }

}

object GatlingFunSpecExample {
  def pageHeader = css("h1")
}
```

Link to the documentation:
https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/functional_specs/